# no instance(s) of type variable(s) K, V exist so that Map<K, V> conforms to HashMap<String, String>

Tags: java, interface, hashmap

I am trying to initialize my `HashMap<String, String> hashMap` in a one liner.

Below is how i am initializing my  `Map<String, String> map` and its just working okay

```
Map<String, String> map = Map.of("name", "Murife");
```

Below is how i am initializing my hashMap

```
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = Map.of("name", "Murife");
```

Is it possible to Initialize a HashMap using Map.of or it is only limited to Map

Comment: Why would you need that? I guess you might want to learn about the benefits of using abstractions. See [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko what if they want to later modify that map?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca if i would like to later modify the map i would just declare an empty Map and later add the items using put but thats not the point here, here i just want to use the HashMap once only thats why declaring an empty map and using put to add items to the map just makes the code a little bit longer, yeah its negligible and it might not matter to you but it does to me

Comment: @EmmanuelNjorodongo my point was that if you did what Alexander Ivanchenko implied and simply declared `hashMap` as a map you would still have obtained an unmodifiable map from the `of` method and you couldn't add elements to it if you needed to. I was answering their "Why would you need that?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Map.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#of(K,V)) doesn't return a `HashMap`, it returns an [unmodifiable map](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#unmodifiable) (what type that is exactly is implementation-dependent and not important), so you can't assign it to a `HashMap`.

You can work around that by using the [`HashMap`'s constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Map)) that accepts (and makes a copy of) another map as an argument.

```
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>(Map.of("name", "Murife"));
```